# Question about Dwapara Yuga and Treta Yuga

Tags: dwapara-yuga, treta-yuga

I found a suggested edit in the review que of Mythology and Folklore SE, which has been there for a while. I see the user is also hanging around this SE @Vivikta. [It's about this question and its answer](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/1844/how-did-the-trimurti-come-into-power)

Could someone clarify if this edit is correct?

**Comment: Krishna incarnated in the Dwapara Yuga and not Treta Yuga. RAma was there in the Treta**

### Original post:

Now, to answer your second question, what caused the people to eventually stop worshiping the lower deities (specifically Indra) - If we go by the mythology, this began changing in **Treta Yuga** when Vishnu incarnated as Krishna. Krishna actively dissuaded people from worshiping lower deities (and any other local gods, forest gods, tree gods, what have you) and exerted strong influence to move people towards monotheism. Gradually people stopped worshiping the lower gods/deities and when Indra got upset and tried to punish people, Krishna protected them from his wrath very publicly to prove his superiority.

### Suggested Edit

Now, to answer your second question, what caused the people to eventually stop worshiping the lower deities (specifically Indra) - If we go by the mythology, this began changing in **Dwapara Yuga** when Vishnu incarnated as Krishna. Krishna actively dissuaded people from worshiping lower deities (and any other local gods, forest gods, tree gods, what have you) and exerted strong influence to move people towards monotheism. Gradually people stopped worshiping the lower gods/deities and when Indra got upset and tried to punish people, Krishna protected them from his wrath very publicly to prove his superiority.

*I recognize this question might not fit and will remove it if required, but I myself am wondering what difference there is.*

Comment: HI! A VERY WARM WELCOME TO HSE!! It's totally correct, what I suggested for the edit. I just happen to read through different stuff on various SE's and **this wrong info** definitely caught my eyes. You may further search this doubt of yours and clear it, by tag searching on this SE itself or better, a quick GOOGLE search will definitely help you out!

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10171/17833

Comment: @Vivikta hi! Thanks for your comment! I had a gut feeling it might be correct but not enough to accept the edit since I need to be really sure. My doubt has been cleared now! I have just accepted it, it will need one more to be totally accepted.

Comment: my pleasure, I could help resolve the doubt! Most welcome.

Comment: @Vivikta feel free to format your info into an answer, I'll gladly accept it so this question can be solved.

Comment: here it is. I posted an answer. Done .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Lord incarnates as *Shri Krishna* in the *Dwapara-Yuga*. The same lord incarnates as *Shri Rama* in the *Treta-Yuga*.**

It's the same lord who incarnates in his various innumerable incarnations (*avatãras*) in all ages or *yugas*. For all chronological order of incarnation, you may refer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21692/what-is-chronological-timeline-in-manvantara-and-mahayuga-of-lord-vishnu-incar?r=SearchResults) please.

FYI, the time within the Hinduism theology is eternal and cyclic (*ananta kaal-chakra*).

---

**Further, here's some extra fun fact that might interest you:**

The order for the Yugas is:

1. Krita Yuga or Sata Yuga
2. Treta Yuga
3. Dwapara Yuga
4. Kali Yuga.

These four together form a *Mahayuga* and 1000 such *Mahuyugas* forms a day of Lord *Brahmã*. An equal time of 1000 *Mahayugas* is the night of Lord *Brahma*.
You may read about the concept of time in Hinduism from [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12518/in-hinduism-how-has-kala-or-time-been-described), [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3078/repetition-of-time-and-yugas-in-hinduism).